# Is the Paypal API able to GIVE payments?

Tags: api, paypal

Like I said. I want to give payments automatically when a user requests it. So far I've only see that you can receive payments (via purchases) using the API, not give away.

Comment: [Like this?](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/direct/payments/paypal-payments/#execute-payment). Just the ID is yours not theirs?

Comment: I may have their ID, I think. I suppose I could store their IDS on my database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such API or automatic bot or whatsoever mechanism that handles such things in PayPal. If you request, then the sender needs to send it manually.

Comment: do you know any other platform that would be able to do that? thanks in advance